# ValueError: Quantizing a tf.keras Model inside another tf.keras Model is not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, quantization-aware-training

I've just got started with Keras/Tensorflow and I am trying to retrain and quantize to int8 a MobileNetV2 but I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Quantizing a tf.keras Model inside another tf.keras Model is not supported.
```

I was following this [guide](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/04/quantization-aware-training-with-tensorflow-model-optimization-toolkit.html) to get around the quantization steps, but I am not exactly sure what exactly I am doing different.

```
IMG_SHAPE = (224, 224, 3)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                                  include_top=False, 
                                                  weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')
])

quantize_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model
q_aware_model = quantize_model(model)
```

Stack Trace:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-34-b724ad4872a5> in <module>()
      9 
     10 quantize_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model
---> 11 q_aware_model = quantize_model(model)

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/quantization/keras/quantize.py in _add_quant_wrapper(layer)
    217     if isinstance(layer, tf.keras.Model):
    218       raise ValueError(
--> 219           'Quantizing a tf.keras Model inside another tf.keras Model is not supported.'
    220       )
    221
```

Comment: I think the error is self-explanatory. You can not quantize this model as it includes base model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. How can I quantize my model in this case?

Comment: I added as an answer, you can mark it as accepted if it solves the issue. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case your `base_model` behaves as if it is a layer. In order to expand it, you need to use Functional API, rather than Sequential API:

```
IMG_SHAPE = (224, 224, 3)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                                  include_top=False, 
                                                  weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(base_model.output)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(base_model.input, x)
model.summary()
```

Notice that model summary shows all of the layers including the `base_model's`. Then you can apply:

```
quantize_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model
q_aware_model = quantize_model(model)
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, I followed your answer and was successfully able to quantize my model

Comment: How can I do that when I am using model = get_model(args,training=True)

Comment: I am not sure what `get_model` function refers to